# can not use WriteableBitmapEX in my windows phone 7 application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, writeablebitmapex

I am working with windows phone 7 app and i need to use WriteableBitmapEX , i downloaded the dll file from [this link](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/releases/view/39577) 
then i unblocked the zip folder then i unzipped the folder .
but when i am trying to use it, i am getting this error

> Error 1   Could not load the assembly file:///C:\Users\User\Desktop\RenderV2\PhoneApp1\Bin\Debug\WriteableBitmapExWinPhone.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web.  If an assembly has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more information

can any one help me please ,
thanks

Comment: Did you actually unblock the dll file itself?

Answer (score 1):

You need to unblock the DLL and there are several ways to do that.

- [Way 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2439489/303696)
- [Way 2](http://www.jamescrowley.co.uk/2011/09/16/unblocking-downloaded-dlls/)