# Suddenly Visual Studio 2013 wouldn't run unit tests because my code wasn't trusted

Tags: visual-studio-2013

OK, so my project (a .NET3.5 DLL) and a unit test project worked up until today when Visual Studio started not trusting something about my project today.  It worked this morning, it doesn't now. The project is on a UNC path pointing to the same machine that I'm developing on.  I understand that all the terrible satanic evils about how performing unit tests on code located in hell can summon demons that immediately fly to the nearest Microsoft office location and devour it.

- The drive IS mapped.
- ReSharper experiences the same issue when I try to run tests through it.
- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/502353/running-unit-tests-from-network-drive This failed to work.
- [Visual Studio Unit Tests : dll is not trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264988/visual-studio-unit-tests-dll-is-not-trusted) doesn't seem like a viable option

The Exception:

Test method MyClass threw exception: 
System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I must ask: Why run them from a share?

Comment: My host machine is a mac.  The development is done on a windows vm and, frankly, it has saved me a lot of headaches this way.  Occasionally I run into the odd issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my search skills need work too.  SO has a post to just what I'm looking for.  Thank you StackOverflow!!

[Keeping Visual Studio Projects on a Network Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159627/keeping-visual-studio-projects-on-a-network-drive)